# Python SQLalchemy - can I pass the connection object between functions?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I have a python application that is reading from mysql/mariadb, uses that to fetch data from an api and then inserts results into another table.

I had setup a module with a function to connect to the database and **return the connection object that is passed to other functions/modules**. However, I believe this might not be a correct approach. The idea was to have a small module that I could just call whenever I needed to connect to the db.

Also note, that I am using the same connection object during loops (and within the loop passing to the db_update module) and call `close()` when all is done.

I am also getting some warnings from the db sometimes, those mostly happen at the point where I call `db_conn.close()`, so I guess I am not handling the connection or session/engine correctly. Also, the connection id's in the log warning keep increasing, so that is another hint, that I am doing it wrong.

```
[Warning] Aborted connection 351 to db: 'some_db' user: 'some_user' host: '172.28.0.3' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Here is some **pseudo code** that represents the structure I currently have:

```
################
## db_connect.py
################
# imports ...
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
def db_connect():
    # get env ...
    db_string = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}"
    try:
        engine = create_engine(db_string)
    except Exception as e:
        return None
    
    db_conn = engine.connect()
    return db_conn


################
## db_update.py
################
# imports ...
def db_insert(db_conn, api_result):
    # ...
    ins_qry = "INSERT INTO target_table (attr_a, attr_b) VALUES (:a, :b);"
    ins_qry = text(ins_qry)
    ins_qry = ins_qry.bindparams(a = value_a, b = value_b)

    try:
        db_conn.execute(ins_qry)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None     
    return True


################
## main.py
################
from sqlalchemy import text
from db_connect import db_connect
from db_update import db_insert

def run():
    try:
        db_conn = db_connect()
        if not db_conn:
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    qry =  "SELECT *
            FROM some_table
            WHERE some_attr IN (:some_value);"
    qry = text(qry)
    search_run_qry = qry.bindparams(
            some_value  = 'abc'
    )
    result_list = db_conn.execute(qry).fetchall()

    for result_item in result_list:
        ## do stuff like fetching data from api for every record in the query result
        api_result = get_api_data(...)
        ## insert into db:
        db_ins_status = db_insert(db_conn, api_result)
        ## ...
    
    db_conn.close

run()
```

**EDIT:** Another question:
a) Is it ok in a loop, that does an update on every iteration to use the same connection, or would it be wiser to instead pass the engine to the `run()` function and call `db_conn = engine.connect()` and `db_conn.close()` just before and after each update?

b) I am thinking about using `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of the loop for the API calls. Would this have implications on how to use the connection, i.e. can I use the same connection for multiple threads that are doing updates to the same table?

*Note: I am not using the ORM feature mostly because I have a strong DWH/SQL background (though not so much as DBA) and I am used to writing even complex sql queries. I am thinking about switching to just using PyMySQL connector for that reason.*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can return/pass connection object as parameter but what is the aim of db_connect method,  except testing connection ? As I see there is no aim of this db_connect method therefore I would recommend you to do this as I done it before.

I would like to share a code snippet from one of my project.

```
def create_record(sql_query: str, data: tuple):
    try:
        connection = mysql_obj.connect()
        db_cursor = connection.cursor()
        db_cursor.execute(sql_query, data)
        connection.commit()
        return db_cursor, connection
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'Connection failed error message: {error}')
```

and then using this one as for another my need

```
db_cursor, connection, query_data = fetch_data(sql_query, query_data)
```

and after all my needs close the connection with this method and method call.

```
def close_connection(connection, db_cursor):
    """
    This method used to close SQL server connection
    """
    db_cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

and calling method

```
 close_connection(connection, db_cursor)
```

I am not sure can I share my github my check this [link](https://github.com/hasanozdem1r/slider_data_api) please. Under model.py you can see database methods and to see how calling them check it main.py

Best,
Hasan.

Comment: Thank you Hasan. Are you using PyMySQL or mysql-connector-python?

Comment: Hello Phil, I use mysql-connector-python but you can fastly configure with another library also. It's not big deal.